# How to retain objects in NSMutableArray IOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an array of custom objects called array which stores a bunch of core data. I use this array to populate my UITableView and to create the cells. I then try to use the same array when UISearch is opened but at this point the array is empty, how could I retain the objects in the array?

**EDIT**

Ok, here is some of my code

my .h file

```
@interface SelectCourses : UIViewController <DataHandlerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
DataHandler *dataHandler;
NSMutableArray *courses;
IBOutlet UITableView *table;
IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchFilter;
//NSMutableArray *filteredCourses;
BOOL isFiltered;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray* filteredCourses;
```

Then my .m file, I have left out several functions which I believe are irrelevant

```
@implementation SelectCourses

@synthesize Delegate;
@synthesize filteredCourses;
...
...

- (void) dataHandlerHasLoadedCourseData:(NSMutableArray *)courseData {
courses = courseData;
[table reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(isFiltered){
    return filteredCourses.count;
}
if (courses) {
    NSLog(@"Count: %i", [courses count]);
    if (courses.count == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return [courses count];
}
else
    return 0;
}
...
...
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchFiltert { 
NSLog(@"searchBarSearchButtonClicked");//More debugging

if(searchFilter.text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:searchFilter.text]);
    isFiltered = true;


    for (Course *course in courses) 
    {
        NSRange codeRange = [course.Code rangeOfString:searchFilter.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange nameRange = [course.Name rangeOfString:searchFilter.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(codeRange.location != NSNotFound || nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredCourses addObject:course];
        }
    }
}
[table reloadData];
}
```

I still get the following error when running the script, I simply assumed it was due to the array being empty

```
2012-04-11 20:54:23.067 scheduleTable[45885:fb03] -[__NSArrayM Code]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897b360
2012-04-11 20:54:23.068 scheduleTable[45885:fb03] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException>     -[__NSArrayM Code]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897b360
```

My course.h and .m looks like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Post;

@interface Course : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@end
```

and

```
#import "Course.h"
#import "Post.h"

@implementation Course

@synthesize Code;
@synthesize Name;
@end
```

Comment: When you put objects into an NSMutableArray they are retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the retain method as Oral b answered but it got me nowhere, I am a bit of a newbie to Objective c which is why I am having the issues.

My courses array was declared in an interface and I was not able to achieve the same result with it as I did with the new array I created just for the search. So in ViewDidLoad I do this

```
coursesForSearch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then where objects were added to my other array I simply added this array and also added the objects to it.

Now I can get objects from the array like so

```
[[coursesForSearch objectAtIndex:500] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, to retain your array, declare the array in your .h file, like so:
`@property (retain) NSMutableArray *yourArrayName;`

Then,synthesize it in your .m file, like this:
`@synthesize yourArrayName;`